# Castle Windsor: Setting a parameter value to an empty string

Tags: castle-windsor

How can I allow one of my string parameters to be an empty string?

I get this error when I try either *nothing* or a single space (names changed):

Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'test.User' (MyNamespace.MyObject). Parameter 'userName' type 'System.String'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it's much easier, and likely more *correct*, to add a constructor that doesn't take the parameter(s) you want to leave blank.

Answer (score 2):

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<Foo>()
      .DependsOn(new
      {
         someString = string.Empty
      }));
```

but first of all, why do you want to set that dependency to empty string? It does feel like hacking to me.

Comment: I was typing up a reason why I wanted to do this only to realize I could just add another constructor that excluded the parameters I wanted to leave empty...  +1 to you for calling me out on the hacking.

Comment: yes, additional .ctor that explicitly excludes the parameter is usually the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

What if there is already a default value, which is null, or some other non-empty string?  One solution is to create a component:

`<component id="emptyString" type="System.String, mscorlib" />`

and then use it in your parameters node:

`<parameters>
<someStringParameter>${emptyString}</someStringParameter>
</parameters>`

But it seems like there ought to be a simpler way.

Comment: Won't work. You can't use `string` as a component. It does not make sense and Windsor won't let you.

Comment: Why do you say it won't work?  I did it before I posted, and the associated parameter value in the constructor was indeed the empty string.  Is it version dependent?  I am using Castle.Core 1.2.0.0, Castle.MicroKernel 2.1.0.0, Castle Windsor 2.1.0.0.

Further, and more importantly, if it doesn't make sense, what is the better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I got the same error as Krzysztof: `Type System.String can not be used as a service. only classes, and interfaces can be exposed as a service.`